# MediaStream value is null when capturing a tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, video-capture

I am trying to capture a video of any opened tab, the code works fine when the extension is in a popup window. The problem is that when losing focus of the popup, the capturing stops. I saw other extensions opens a separate window when beginning the capturing so that the user can do other things while the tab is being recorded. I did the same but now when I try to capture any tab, it returns the stream as a null value. can someone explain why and how to fix this?

```
function startCapture(tabId) {
  chrome.tabCapture.capture(
    {
      video: true,
      audio: true,
      videoConstraints: {
        mandatory: { chromeMediaSource: "tab", chromeMediaSourceId: tabId },
      },
    },
    function (stream) {
      console.log(stream);
      createTabsRecorders(tabId, stream);
      mediaRecorders[tabId].recorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
        if (event.data.size > 0) {
          mediaRecorders[tabId].chunks.push(event.data);
        }
      };
      mediaRecorders[tabId].recorder.onstop = () => {
        const blob = new Blob(mediaRecorders[tabId].chunks, {
          type: "video/webm",
        });

        // Create a local URL for the blob
        const videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        // Create a download link (anchor tag)
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.style.display = "none";
        a.href = videoURL;
        a.download = "captured_video.webm";

        // Add the link to the document and trigger a click event to initiate the download
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();
        a.remove();

        // Clear the chunks array
        mediaRecorders[tabId].chunks = [];
      };

      mediaRecorders[tabId].recorder.start();
    }
  );
}
```